# Visual Basic 6 App on Windows 10 x64

Tags: 64-bit, windows-10-desktop

Long story, so please bear with me.

I have an app that I wrote back in 2001 for an AS400/iSeries ISV.  Basically, it takes drawing commands off of the AS400, and creates a windows graphic (bmp) file  so that they can then display the graphic in their application.  Everything has worked great over the years.  Now, they have a new customer that is having problems running the application.  The problem is that when my application is called from the ISV's software, windows generates a message stating that the application is a 16 bit application and can not be run.  I am sure that the application is a 32 bit application.  We have tested this on 3 machines running Windows 10 x64 at the ISV's office and do not get the error.  We get the graphic and everything runs as intended.

I am guessing that the problem is that the WOW64 layer is somehow not enabled or not setup.  Questions:

- I thought that VB6 apps were all 32 bit.  Is that correct?
- Is it possible to not install the WOW64 layer during a Windows setup?
- Is it somehow possible in Windows 10 x64 to not enable 32 bit apps?

If you have any other suggestions, we are glad to hear them.

TIA and for your time.

Wally

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371790(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The problem is now solved.  I was not given the full details, but was told it was an issue with the folder that the app was installed into.
Thanks!